Startup probe failed with "context deadline exceeded" after changing GCP billing account
We are facing an issue during the deployment of our application in Kubernetes. The pod's startup probe is failing with the following error:

Startup probe failed: Get "http://10.200.1.231:8080/api/is_alive": context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)

Previously, everything was working perfectly. However, after changing the billing account in Google Cloud Platform (GCP), the issue started occurring.
Probe configuration:
readinessProbe:
    httpGet:
        path: /api/v1/ready
        port: 8080
      initialDelaySeconds: 20
      periodSeconds: 10
      timeoutSeconds: 5
      failureThreshold: 3
    livenessProbe:
      httpGet:
        path: /api/v1/healthz
        port: 8080
      initialDelaySeconds: 30
      periodSeconds: 20
      timeoutSeconds: 5
      failureThreshold: 3
    startupProbe:
      httpGet:
        path: /api/v1/startup
        port: 8080
      initialDelaySeconds: 15
      periodSeconds: 60
      timeoutSeconds: 5
      failureThreshold: 3        
    resources:
      requests:
       memory: "2Gi"
       cpu: "2000m"
      limits:
       memory: "2Gi"
       cpu: "2000m"

Pod
What we've tried

Verified the application and probe configuration, which hasn't been changed.
Checked network connectivity, and there doesn’t seem to be any obvious problem.
Ensured that the Kubernetes cluster has sufficient resources.


Are any of the probes depending on healthy resources like db? With e.g. Spring Boot, probes can include db health check. BR

Try to set the imagePullPolicy to always if not so. May be you are running a cached image.
